# Research Experience for Undergraduates: Summer Programs (that accept non-American applicants)

Tags: soft-question, education, big-list, career-development

There are many [*summer research programs*](http://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/list_result.cfm?unitid=5044) in the United States, targeted at good motivated undergraduate students majoring in mathematics.

The main aspects that characterize such programs are: **(a)** a great deal of *lectures* on specific topics; **(b)** the chance to gain some hands-on experience with *research projects*.

Most of these programs, however, (if not all of them) are hosted by American Universities and require that the applicants are American or permenant residents in the United States. Also, even if students outside the U.S. are allowed to apply, they generally do not receive funds.

> **Question:** Are there any such programs *outside the U.S.*? Or are there any programs in the U.S. that accept *also non-American applicants*?

---

**Remark**: A similar question was asked on *[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13847/research-experience-for-undergraduates-summer-programs)*, but it seems appropriate to share this question with the larger (and maybe younger) community of *Mathematics Stack Exchange*.

Comment: Budapest Semesters in Mathematics isn't a summer program, but it's open to Canadian undergraduates as well.

Comment: Qiaochu: Max is not from North America (acc. to his information page) so the Budapest program isn't open to  him. Max: why are you asking about *summer* programs instead of other opportunities like, say, semester-abroad programs? Are you specifically wanting a research experience rather than, say, a chance to take some math courses in another country?

Comment: @ Keith: I think the universities I consider studying at already have such semester-abroad programs. These programs are for graduate students. Such a program would be nice, *too*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some summer research opportunities in the US that fund non-US citizens. (I realize that you were asking for programs outside the US, but you framed your question in terms of being disappointed about having to fund it yourself so I thought this list might be helpful)

(I'm new, so the system won't let me post more than one hyperlink)

Research in Industrial Projects for Students (RIPS) 2011 at UCLA (Also has a program in HongKong)

http://math.williams.edu/small/application-information/  (their website says they have funded non-US students in the past)

NIMBios 2011 Summer Program
National Institute for Mathematical and Biological Synthesis (NIMBioS)
at the University of Tennessee, Knoxville

DIMACS REU
DIMACS/DIMATIA REU
CCICADA REU
Rutgers Math Department REU (foreign students enrolled at a U.S. university are eligible under the CCICADA program)

Mathematical and Theoretical Biology Institute MTBI Summer Research Program

Comment: Thank you *very* much, jamie. You make me feel ashamed of my googling abilities. Though I'm (at least currently) most interested in pure mathematics (I'm most impressed with SMALL), I appreciate all the options provided by you. I hope more answers like yours will follow! If not, I will accept yours.

Comment: By the way, have you ever heard of mathoverflow? It is a website that is similar too math.stackexchange in much respects, the only difference is that it aims to be a venue of questions and answers on mathematics at research level. A question that is nearly identical you just gave an answer to was posed there. I think the person who posed the question there would like this answers of your's a lot, too. see:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13847/research-experience-for-undergraduates-summer-programs

Comment: Max--thanks!  I've posted the above over at mathoverflow too.  I'm curious to see what other people come up with as well.

Comment: DIMACS also sponsors a mathematical biology/epidemiology workshop that takes US, Canadian and African students.

Answer (score 2):

As an undergraduate in the UK, I did a summer research project in analytic number theory that was funded by the [EPSRC Vacation Bursaries Scheme](http://www.epsrc.ac.uk/skills/students/dta/vacationbursaries/).  It involved working under the supervision of an advisor on an individual project for approximately 8 weeks, and was a really good opportunity to gain research experience.  I'm not sure what the constraints for eligibility are regarding nationality/citizenship, but the website I've linked to provides information about participating universities, who might have further information.

There is a similar scheme specifically for mathematics funded by the [LMS](http://www.lms.ac.uk/grants/undergraduate-research-bursaries)

Comment: thank you Lea. I searched for more information regarding which kinds of mathematics are covered in the Vacaion Bursary Schemes of several different universities, but I couldn't find a lot... Do you know where to find such information? Did you know before hand your vacation bursary covered analytic number theory?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know very much how the bursaries are organized or where to find out more about them.  Yes, I did know what my vacation bursary would cover in advance-my professor sketched the research project that we would be working on together as part of the application for the bursary.  I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful-good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Individual universities may have funding available, so it would be worth asking your own university. Three programmes I know of are:

University of Toronto (Canada): http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/15-16/summer-research15/

Weizmann Institute (Israel): http://wws.weizmann.ac.il/feinberg/index.php?q=content/about-program-0

Not strictly research, but PROMYS in Europe are looking for counsellors. It's based in Oxford, UK: http://www.promys-europe.org

But be aware that deadlines for this year may have passed.