# List of mathematical Summer schools (particulary in Europe)

Tags: soft-question, education

I would like to apply for a summer school. Particulary it should take place in Europe and center on the topic numerical analysis.

Is there something like a comprehensive list of summer schools?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/summer-programs-to-gain-research-experience-as-an-undergraduate-outside-the-unit

Comment: Wiki-hammered. I am somewhat doubtful of this question's usefulness on Math.SE, as it is rather temporally bound.