# Undergraduate research program (REU) with focus on nonlinear analysis (accessible to European students)

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question, education, nonlinear-system

> > Is there an undergraduate summer research program (**REU**) -- to which also
> >     European students can apply -- which usually has projects (i.e., specialized faculty) on ***nonlinear analysis*** (i.e., nonlinear *PDE*,etc.) and ***mathematical physics***?

**Remark:** This question is about a specific kind of REU, which cannot be found among the ones listed at *[Research Experience for Undergraduates: Summer Programs (that accept non-American applicants)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/research-experience-for-undergraduates-summer-programs-that-accept-non-america)*.